# Should I make restful web app multiple modules

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, dao

Our group used to build web applications using jersey. Usually we would have two modules, dao and api. Dao consists of entity classes and dao interfaces/implementation classes, while Api module has all the rest api classes. Recently, we have been transitioning from Jersey to Spring MVC and Spring Boot. Since we are using Spring Data and JPA, there seems to have no need of having a dao package for all the interfaces and implementations. Instead, JPA repositories take care of all the data access. Services are built over the repository layer. It feels more natural to have the JPA repository stuff in the same module as services, controller, etc.

What is the best practice of organizing a restful web api project? Should I set up the project as a two module application just like what we did before, that is having all the entities in one module (model or dao) and the rest goes to another module called api? If this is the way to go, should I keep persistence.xml which contains all the ORM mapping for entities within the entity module or the api module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly my opinion of 1 vs 2 modules, but I don't think there is one single answer. It probably depends on how large the web app is. Is it a single API in the same codebase/build that's basic CRUD or do you have many separate, but smaller APIs creating more of a micro-service environment. We had a few larger monolithic apps where we did separate out the Dao stuff into separate modules. We also separated 3rd party dependencies such as Google or Stripe into a module even separate from Dao stuff. Makes it easier to create a separate jar if there was a need.

Regardless, what's more important is you can ensure you have one way dependency. Meaning the API is dependent on the DAO but not the opposite. Curious what others think